# How to bound difference of convex optimization problems, when the closed-form solution doesn't exit?

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Let $z = \langle z_1 ,...,z_m \rangle$ where $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, we define $g(z):= \arg \min_{y \in \mathbb{R}^{d}} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \parallel z_i -y \parallel_2$. We say $z \Delta z'=1$, if $z'$ differs only in the last element with $z$, in other words $\forall i \in [m-1], z_i=z'_i$, but $z_m \neq z'_m$, we want to compute $\max_{z': z\Delta z'=1} \parallel g(z) - g(z') \parallel_1 $ , any clue how to start on this?